Does covariances uniquely determine the joint distribution?
We know that if we have a random vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$ following a multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$, then we have (1) each $x_i$ follows a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_{ii})$ and (2) the covariance between each pair $x_i$ and $x_j$ is $\operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j) = \Sigma_{ij}$.
Seemingly this is not the only case where we have (1) each $x_i$ follows a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_{ii})$ and (2) the covariance between each pair $x_i$ and $x_j$ is $\operatorname{Cov}(x_i, x_j) = \Sigma_{ij}$, and I saw an example at Given a random vector has univariate normal marginals, and a positive definite Covariance. Does this mean the vector is multivariate normal?.
Q: What are some systematic ways to construct such random vectors? Or are there special well-known distributions satisfying those two conditions other than multivariate normal distribution?

Mean and cavariance determining the joint distribution is a very special property of joint  normal distribution. Almost anything else will violate this.

For constructing $X\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ you write
$\Sigma =UD^2U^T$ with $D=\mathrm {diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ and $U$ orthogonal matrix. Next you take $Z=(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ with the $Z_i$'s independent and $N(0,1)$. Then $X=UDZ\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ since $E(XX^T)=\Sigma.$
